# How to get the upgrade code using the MsiGetProductInfo and MsiOpenDatabase?

Tags: c++, windows-installer

I have read a few posts on StackOverflow itself about getting the UpgradeCode using 2 queries. First, use MsiGetProductInfo to get the database path (how?!) to open the database which will contain the UpgradeCode. Please provide the API call to fetch the database path! Urgent.

Comment: I need to understand what you are doing more to give you a proper answer.

Comment: Call MsiEnumProducts to find the package code if you only know the name, then call MsiGetProductInfo with the product code to get INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE property (i.e. the "database"/msi file), open the database, find UpgradeCode in the property table, done. That answers your question - but I'm not sure why you would need this in such a manner.

Comment: @saschabeaumont You should convert your comment to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call MsiEnumProducts to find the package code if you only know the name, then call MsiGetProductInfo with the product code to get INSTALLPROPERTY_LOCALPACKAGE property (i.e. the "database"/msi file), open the database, find UpgradeCode in the property table, done. That answers your question - but I'm not sure why you would need this in such a manner.